# How to connect holoviews in backend with bokehjs frontend

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, datashader

I'm developing a webpage that needs to plot millions of points, so I'm using ***HoloViews*** in my backend to generate a plot and send it as a ***Bokeh*** model to my frontend which uses ***Bokehjs***.

So in the API I call a function that does this

```
hv.extension("bokeh")
points = hv.Points(df)
datashaded = hd.datashade(points, aggregator=ds.count_cat('cat')).redim.range(x=(-5,5),y=(-5,5))
plot = hv.render(datashaded)
return json.dumps(json_item(plot))
```

and returns a Bokeh model that is sent in JSON format to the frontend.

The function `hd.datashade` renders a Bokeh plot and internally calls datashader to create the images as you control zoom. But the problem is that as I call this function just once through the API, zoom controls don't create a new image, instead it just make pixels bigger.

I need a way to have a "live python process running" as [documentation](http://datashader.org/getting_started/3_Interactivity.html) states so I can have zoom controls and tooltips. But I have no idea how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you dump things into JSON, there's no longer any connection to the Python code.  Instead, you can do something like in http://pyviz.org/tutorial/13_Deploying_Bokeh_Apps.html:

```
hv.extension("bokeh")
points = hv.Points(df)
datashaded = hd.datashade(points, aggregator=ds.count_cat('cat')).redim.range(x=(-5,5),y=(-5,5))
doc = hv.renderer('bokeh').server_doc(datashaded)
doc.title = 'HoloViews Bokeh App'
```

And then run `bokeh serve --show file.py` to launch [Bokeh Server](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) on your file.  Bokeh server will ensure that a Python process is running, provide a webserver for displaying your HTML/JS, and set up connections between them.

Comment: Thank you, what you told me works, but I still need to send the plot to a different application that uses bokehjs, that's why I sent a JSON with the bokeh model. 

How can I make the connection between bokehjs in my app and the bokeh server ?

Comment: That depends on your application.  Various people have embedded Bokeh into various types of application, and hopefully you can find something similar to what you have in mind in the Bokeh docs or on stackoverflow.